# jaxb - marshalled root element with full java package

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

im working on a project with jaxb maven plugin. (maven 3.2.2, maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.1, java8)

i use

```
<bindingIncludes>
    <bindingInclude>...</bindingInclude>
</bindingIncludes>
```

for specifing package of generated classes and

```
<generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc-dir
</generateDirectory>
```

for specifing output directory.

Im trying to understand what would cause marshaller to work in two different ways:

actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<com.test.app.Foo>
...
</com.test.app.Foo>
```

expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Foo>
...
</Foo>
```

full java package is only visible for root element.

thanks in advance

edit:

generated code

```
package com.test.app;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    (...)
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {
...
}
```

Comment: Please show your generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any1 seeing similar issues:

in this case i was creating JAXBElement using my own QName using as one of arguments Foo.class.getName()

removing JAXBElement totally and passing Foo to marshaller fixed the issue, using Foo.class.getSimpleName() would probably also work